# Platform to ask questions about one's professional future

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any place one can consult with the community what kind of job he needs to take? I think it would be beneficial for others to consult before taking a pace in the professional world.

Comment: The only place I can think of is http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ but [it's explicitly off-topic there](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5):

Other than chat, no.

Stack Exchange is not built to handle discussions. We just about manage on meta sites, but it's clunky and doesn't sit well with some people.

There are plenty of other places on the internet where discussions are welcome, you will need to use one of those.

As for questions - these are explicitly proscribed on both [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are:

1. Only of interest to you.
2. Attract answers that are purely opinion based.

Comment: Didn't mean literally discuss, Q&A format would be nice too.

Comment: @0x90: in that case, could you provide an example of a question that you think would fit? Not quite sure what type of question you have in mind.

Comment: Let's say I am considering to stay in an Embedded SW Engineer position, or moving to a Verification Engineer position. what are the Pros Cons.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about career choices were made off-topic on Stack Exchange because they tend to be very personal, and don't help future visitors. This means they're not only off-topic on Stack Overflow, but also on Programmers and The Workplace.

However, Stack Exchange has been trying some new grounds. Questions recommending third-party resources were made off-topic because they attracted opinionated answers and spam. But Stack Exchange is trying to make them work with the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

So you could make a proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). Be sure to make a compelling case, to make clear how this would fit into SE's mission of "making the internet a better place"!! Be sure to explain how this Q&A would either help future visitors, or explain why in this particular case, the requirement of helping future visitors could be waived. Either way you will encounter a lot of resistance, so think long and hard about how this site should work.